# Should questions about upcoming hardware be accepted?

Tags: discussion, questions

If I were to ask about hardware that is going to come out, such as: "Is the new Pascal GPU architecture worth waiting for, based on rumors and details nVidia has released? Or should I just buy a GTX 960?" Should this type of question be allowed, or should it be off-topic? I'm kind of leaning towards this being allowed, but I am not sure...

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/88/155) for some additional insight here.

Answer (score 1):

My official answer for this is **maybe**.

**Potentially on-topic**
These questions definitely have a place within the scope seeing as the author wants recommendations for hardware to make a purchase decision. As long as the hardware or technology is announced *and is definitely going to be released* (meaning the company officially stated its release), reasonable recommendations can be made based on the new hardware.

**Potentially off-topic**
If the hardware or technology is in any way at all rumored and there is no official statement of its future release, reliable recommendations can't be made based on information available to the public.

So basically the unreleased product needs officially stated, publicly available specs that can provide a basis for recommendations. If it doesn't have this, the question will probably be very unstable.

Also, I think it would be good if the question linked to official specs of some kind otherwise the stability of the question would again be affected.

Comment: I agree on both points.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very opinion based, in a bad way (since all recommendations are opinions). When something hasn't been released yet we have two things to go on:

- Hype
- Manufacturer promises

Neither of these allow us, as "experts", to provide an answer based on our experiences with the hardware.

"Worth waiting for" makes this even harder to answer. Now we have to use hype/promises to make a judgement call on whether or not unreleased hardware will do what you want at a price point that may still be an estimate.

Finally, hardware is promised and not delivered frequently. Vaporware is annoying and frustrating if the hype was big enough.

I think we should be sticking to hardware that is released.